# VS2012 C# Application cannot save value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The same code,Application's key can be saved in vs2010 after closing the page,but cannot be save in vs2012

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object value = Application["a"]; // value = 'abc' in 2010,value = null in 2012
    Application["a"] = "abc"; //save the value
}
```

If i closing the page , and restart it ,Application's key is exists in vs2010,but it had nothing in vs2012,it seems no matter how many values set in Application,if you restart the page, it's all gone..
 why is that ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The Application object lives within the application pool within IIS (I'm presuming you're using IIS).  The contents of the Application object will be reset when / if the application restarts.